# Cannot instantiate a nested class inside main()

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

The simple code below generates an error:

> non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

What does this error mean? Ok I understand that this is a wrong syntax for instantiating the inner class objects.But I am not clear how I am "referencing non static variable this from a static context" by doing so."

```
public class Test{
    class Test1{}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // generates an error
    new Test1(); 
    }
}
```

does new Test1() in above code means this.new Test1();

Comment: you need an instance of outer class to do so, new Test().new Test1();

Comment: Mean exactly what it says

Comment: Try `new Test().new Test1();`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java inner class and static nested class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Comment: aioobe, is new Test1() equivalent to this.new Test1() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application requirements allow you to make the `class Test1` a `static` class, then do this.

```
public class Test {

    static class Test1 {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test.Test1();
    }
}
```

If the `class Test1` needs to be **non-static**, then do this.

```
public class Test {

    class Test1 {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().new Test1();
    }
}
```

**Notice the syntax of the instantiation in both the cases.**

Comment: If i simply do new Test1() as in my question then is it equivalent to this.newTest1() ?

Comment: FIrst point..... You cannot access `this` in `main()` beacause `this` is non-static and you **CANNOT** access non-static member from any static method.




Second point...... if `class Test1` is `static`, then you can access it directly from `main()`.. In this case, `new Test.Test1()` and `new Test1()` is same.

Answer (score 0):

You can see below code:

```
public class Test {

static class Test1 {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test.Test1 obj = new Test.Test1();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a reference to the outer class `Test` as well.

```
Test1 inner = new Test().new Test1();
```

If inner `Test1` was static then it would be

```
 Test1 inner = Test.new Test1();
```